New VCL component - Add Style using Bitmap Style Designer
In RAD Studio 12.2 C++Builder, I created a new component called TGroupBoxE derived from TGroupBox. It inherited all of the graphic properties of TGroupBox.

I want the new component to not use the TGroupBox style, but a new TGroupBoxE style which I will create using the Bitmap Style Designer. In the Bitmap Style Designer, I loaded and copied GroupBox (TSeStyleObject). I called it GroupBoxE and changed the rendering so that it does not display any frame.

The new component is defined correctly in the Samples category, and it can be used in the application.
How do I define TSeStyleObject correctly in the TGroupBoxE component so that it does not use the visual style of TGroupBox but instead uses my new design without frames?
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "GroupBoxE.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//-----------------------GroupBoxE.cpp---------------------------------------
__fastcall TGroupBoxE::TGroupBoxE(TComponent* Owner)
    : TGroupBox(Owner)//, FFrameWidth(1), FCustomShowFrame(true)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TRect __fastcall TGroupBoxE::GetClientRect()
{
    TRect Rect = TGroupBox::GetClientRect();
    if (Caption.IsEmpty())
    {
        int CaptionHeight = Canvas->TextHeight("A"); 
        Rect.Top -= CaptionHeight;  
    }
    return Rect;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TGroupBoxE::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_SIZE && FOnResize) FOnResize(this);
    TGroupBox::WndProc(Message);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Groupboxe
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TGroupBoxE)};
        RegisterComponents(L"Samples", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


//--------------------------------GroupBoxE.h--------------------------------
#ifndef GroupBoxEH
#define GroupBoxEH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PACKAGE TGroupBoxE : public TGroupBox
{
private:
    TNotifyEvent FOnResize; 
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message) override;
public:
    __fastcall TGroupBoxE(TComponent* Owner) override;
__published:
    virtual TRect __fastcall GetClientRect() override;
    __property TNotifyEvent OnResize = {read=FOnResize, write=FOnResize};
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif


If the only reason you are subclassing TGroupBox is to create a new style for it and in particular to not show the frame, then why not just set the ShowFrame property to false instead?
If you have other functionality in your subclassed GroupBox or if I have misunderstood your question, then I would tag Delphi as well because you will engage a much larger base of users for something that is more VCL specific than C++ specific.
(I wish I could have just left a comment but because the way SO works is that I have to generate enough points to do that and one way is by submitting answers.  It seems odd to me that it is more difficult to comment than to provide an answer.)

It would be nice if ShowFrame only displayed the frame, but unfortunately that's not the case. When ShowFrame=false, both the border and background rendering are turned off. That's why I had to make a new component where I can turn off the border and background separately via ShowFrame.

Understood.  I see your answer below and yes per control styling is the way to go.  But you do not need to subclass a component to do that unless you have specific functionality you want to add other than fooling around with the style.

So the official answer is:
VCL Style has fixed structure and you can't add new objects as in FMX Style.
You can create new VCL Style and use per-control styling (TControl.StyleName property).
If you want to use your style for group box then change "GroupBox"
object in MyStyle.vsf ("MyStyle" style name, for example).
Add your style to the project and set TGroupBox.StyleName = 'MyStyle'.
